# Getting an error message from remote as I pass XML to a not further specified XML Customer prefix="ECON" web service written in some .Net with PHP

Tags: php, .net, xml, soap, nusoap

I'm attempting to access a method on a web service which should return a 'Customer ID' when an XML document in the following format is submitted:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer prefix="ECON">
    <Property Name="First Name" Value="test"/>
    <Property Name="Surname" Value="user"/>
    <Property Name="Company" Value="company"/>
    <Property Name="Telephone" Value="123456"/>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I'm creating the XML document like this:

```
    try {
      // a new dom object, make tidy // 
        $dom = new domDocument; 
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
      // create the root and simple xml elements // 
        $root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement( "Customers" ));
        $sxe = simplexml_import_dom( $dom );
      // add the customer node with prefix //
        $customer = $sxe->addchild("Customer");
        $customer->addAttribute("prefix", "ECON");
      // add first name element //
        $firstname = $customer->addChild("Property");
        $firstname->addAttribute("Name", "Title");
        $firstname->addAttribute("Value", $first_name);
      // add surname element //
        $surname = $customer->addChild("Property");
        $surname->addAttribute("Name", "Surname");
        $surname->addAttribute("Value", $last_name);
      // add company element //
        $company = $customer->addChild("Property");
        $company->addAttribute("Name", "Postcode");
        $company->addAttribute("Value", $company_name);
      // add telephone element //
        $phone = $customer->addChild("Property");
        $phone->addAttribute("Name", "Telephone");
        $phone->addAttribute("Value", $telephone);
} 
catch( Exception $e ) 
{ 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

And submitting it to the method, with the authentication from a previous method, like this:

```
$result = $client2->call('InsertCustomer', array('AuthenticationString' => $authenticate['AuthenticateUserResult'], 'Customers' => $sxe->asXML()));
```

But it keeps throwing up the dreaded 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error, I think I need to submit the XML differently to account for the service being based on .NET but no amount of googling is pointing me in the right direction. Can anybody help?

Comment: You're going to have to ask the authors of said service why it throws that exception and what you need to provide in order to prevent that. We can't know from given XML, it depends on the implementation.

Comment: What is throwing the error exactly? A line in your script or is that the response from the server? If it's in your script, try to isolate exactly which piece of code

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster, I have asked the authors, awaiting a response now, there is a method which describes the 'Customer' record in the database, would a dump of that help? There are some required fields which I have tried entering as blanks, but get the same error.

Comment: @jacobwalker0814 it is the response from the server that is giving the error, which is why I believe this is a problem with the format of the XML I'm submitting.

Comment: This was one of those frustratingly simple problems to solve, 'prefix' needed to be 'Prefix'... that was throwing the whole thing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a simple case of using the wrong case for one of the XML attributes, I didn't realise how crucial this was for .NET as I'm used to the often forgiving beast that is PHP.

If you're writing a PHP script that communicates with .NET or ASP be sure to check all of your capitalisation if you are hitting a problem that doesn't make sense.